# Hide arrows from filter in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide the arrows of the fields in the range that I applied filter manually.
For example I have filtered the range A5:S500 by the column R and then I need a code that hides the arrows from the filter (the first row which is row 5)
I have tried this

```
Sub HideArrows()
    Dim c As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        For Each c In .Range("A5:S5")
            .Range("A5:S5").AutoFilter Field:=c.Column, VisibleDropDown:=False
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

But this takes too long time moreover it removes the filtered range
Is there a way to hide the arrows of the filter without removing the filtered range?

Comment: see:   https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2012/05/29/hide-arrows-in-excel-autofilter/

Comment: I already have a look before posting the question and the code's idea is based on it. But will I have to loop through each cell and why the code is slow although it is simple loop.

Comment: The easiest way I found to get around this problem is to set your autofilter in an empty row and then hide the entire row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possible ways to workaround this issue; you will need to modify the worksheet, row, and range to meet your specific needs.

The first one inserts an empty row where you want to insert the autofilter, after inserting the autofilter, it will hide the row.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Rows(5).EntireRow.Insert
    With Range("A5:S5")
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="2"
        .EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End With
End With
```

The other way; is to set your range in one column, which will insert only one drop down (in the first cell of the range) and still filter the used range. When you add `VisibleDropDown:=False`, the single drop down will be hidden.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:C20")
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, VisibleDropDown:=False
End With
```